# MrNom, crash when hitting play

Tags: android, crash

I am having an issue here and not quite sure what the problem is, done a little googling and can't find much but I suspect it has something to do with the way my images are being fetched or the way the random placement of the stain is being calculated, sometimes the game will start up but I can only get to 2-3 stains max and then it normally crashes as I enter the same grid as the next one. This makes me suspect it could also be the code that calculates when the head of the snake is on the same grid as a stain...so many things I don't even know what is broken and what isn't :D, the debugger always points to this area which is line 151 > 158 of GameScreen.java:

```
    Image stainImage = null;
    if (stain.type == Stain.TYPE_1)
        stainImage = Assets.stain1;
    if (stain.type == Stain.TYPE_2)
        stainImage = Assets.stain2;
    if (stain.type == Stain.TYPE_3)
        stainImage = Assets.stain3;
    **int x = stain.x * 32;**
    int y = stain.y * 32;
    g.drawImage(stainImage, x, y);
```

It points to the second line, I have removed this code completely and the game no longer crashes when I hit play, however when I touch the screen to confirm I am ready and cahnge the game state to "ready" it obviously crashes.

The error log shows this:

- 07-29 16:18:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(5102): FATAL EXCEPTION:
  Thread-12
- 07-29 16:18:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):
  java.lang.NullPointerException
- 07-29 16:18:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):  at
  com.stephengibson.mrnom.GameScreen.drawWorld(GameScreen.java:158)
- 07-29 16:18:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):  at
  com.stephengibson.mrnom.GameScreen.present(GameScreen.java:130)
- 07-29 16:18:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):  at
- com.stephengibson.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:46)
- 07-29 16:18:08.516: E/AndroidRuntime(5102):  at
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

I have checked the lines that the error report is complaining about, GameScren line 130 looks like so:

```
    drawWorld(world);
    if (state == GameState.Ready)
        drawReadyUI();
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        drawRunningUI();
    if (state == GameState.Paused)
        drawPausedUI();
    if (state == GameState.GameOver)
        drawGameOverUI();
```

And AndroidFastRenderview line 46 looks like this:

```
    game.getCurrentScreen().present(deltaTime);
```

---

I hope I have supplied enough information, I have followed the book pretty well and have spend the better half of 3-4 hours going back and forth and cross checking all the code, adding stuff and taking away parts to try and figure out the problem.

Sorry for the long question haha, thanks.

Comment: What is line 158 of GameScreen.java?

Comment: sorry I fail, line 158 of GameScreen.java is the first block of code I posted, shall edit to reflect

Comment: Which line EXACTLY? There are no line numbers on StackOverflow. Make it bold or show it separately or something.

Comment: sorry, being an idiot here.

       int x = stain.x * 32;

Comment: It's fine, first time is always rough.

Answer (score 1):

`stain` must be when you reach that line in your code. Make sure it is initialized to some value before your code reaches that line.

`NullPointerException` occurs when you try to access a member of or call a method on an object that is null (meaning you are trying to dereference a null pointer). Whenever you see that in a stack trace, find that line and figure out what object on that line could be null.

Comment: Hm right, well I was running it again there before I changed it so I could make sure the error log was the same...it wasn't.

The error log seems to be showing a different problem on another line:

07-29 16:56:31.236: E/AndroidRuntime(6200):  at com.stephengibson.mrnom.GameScreen.drawWorld(GameScreen.java:152)

That is coming after the NullPointerException, the rest of the log remains the same, the line 152 is this:

          if (stain.type == Stain.TYPE_1)

I am pretty stumped on what to do here, I am pretty new to Java and Android hehe

Comment: Fix one thing at a time and run it again. Repeat until no more errors.

Comment: Got it fixed, I had not actually created an instance of a Stain in my World.java, meaning there was no random generation, so therefore the gamescreen could not resolve a type and paint it. Thanks for the help! :D Look forward to being apart of this website :)